# programing function in python

Tags: python, function, count

I'm trying to create a function that take two parameters: D = digit (0-9) and n = positive number.

If the D is parity number, the function should give me 0 but ,if the D is odd number, the function should count numbers of odd number I have in n.

There is a problem with this code but I don't know what:

```py
def testD(D,n):
    if D % 2 == 0:
        return 0
    count = 0
    while n > 0:
        if(n%10) %2==1:
            count +=1
        n=n/10
    return count
```

Comment: What debugging have you done? Where have you narrowed the problem down to?

Comment: It would be good to give an example of what you expect to be the outcome for a test case.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), take [the SO tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour), read about [how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I changed 2 things :

- `while n > 1:` instead of `while n > 0:` otherwise your loop never stops
- `n=n//10` instead of `n=n/10`, where `//` is the euclidian division, which is what you need here

You should try this :

```
def testD(D,n):
    if D % 2 == 0:
        return 0
    count = 0
    while n > 1:
        if(n%10) %2==1:
            count +=1
        n=n//10
    return count

print(testD(7, 555))
# output : 3 (because 7 is odd, and there is 3 odd digits in 555)
```

Comment: Why? You should explain what you changed and why it's significant.

Comment: Why? What changes did you make? Why did you make those changes? Why do you think those changes would solve the OP's problem? Please take some time to read [how to write good answers](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).